# Persistent Volume deletion issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-eks, pv

while I scale down EC2 node count into zero (basically EC2 gets terminated)under each ASG of EKS cluster and scale up again , then dynamically provisioned EBS(PV) volume gets deleted , though "Delete on termination" flag is set to "No" in case of EBS(PV). why its happening ? suppose if my cluster has currently 3 nodes and if I down 1 node or two nodes then EBS volume persists. But when I down all 3 nodes under ASG then EBS volume gets deleted. Need to know the root cause of it . Thanks in advance.

I tried by checking different scenario like terminating one EC2 /two EC2 instances , but EBS volume still there. Checked PV reclaim policy was mentioned as  Delete, but PV lifecycle doesn't depend on Nodes termination  so I ignored this logic.

The above scenario is happening when I scale up EKS cluster after 18 to 24 hours later from scale down process . If I scale up after 1 or 2 hour or so from scale down process , then EBS volume is not getting deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be the case, I myself downscale our worker nodes to 0 many times and never have the PVs got deleted, can you check the `Volumes` in AWS EC2 dashboard and see if they are actually getting deleted from there or not?

Comment: Yes I checked volumes after scale up all three nodes..volumes got deleted and pvc status is showing bound and holding deleted node info.